# os.walk - counting the directories traversed

Tags: directory, traversal, os.walk, dirname

I have written a code to traverse directories using the os.walk to search for a specific type of file.

```
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(directory):
        for name in files:
            if name.lower().endswith(".txt"):
               print ()
        cl += 1
```

This works perfectly fine for the search but I would like to know if there is a way where I can track the number of directories (dirname) being traversed ? Ex: there are 10 folders containing a .txt file and tracking the no of times dirnames changes I need to get 10 in a counter.

Sorry, I could not find if there was a post about this earlier. If some one can help me track the old post or help with answer for this - that would be fantastic.

Comment: doesn't `cl` do the counting?

Comment: @WorldSEnder : well that is useful only in counting the number of files in all the directories. I wanted to know if there was a way to get the name of the directory which I was traversing at a given moment. 

I did this after the if statement : 
        fullAfpFilePath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
        fileLabels.append(fullAfpFilePath)
        Labels.append(dirpath.split("\\")[-1])

Labels gave me answer.